# Multiple questions (date, weather, location)

Tags: ios, date, location, weather

I'm creating an app that I believe that will be helpful to students. I want to include weather (only temperature) based on location. For example, if I was going from one city to the next, I want it to automatically update for the new city. How would I do this? For my second question, I'm also wanting to put a date (i.e. Saturday, August 30, 2014) into a label. How would I do this?

I have never touched on location and weather before. Sorry for not providing any example code.

Comment: If you are not convinced with my answer you could ask me I am here for  you

Answer (score 2):

**Location name:**

Find the geocoordinates using location manager

Use Google reverse geolocation API to find out the location name

**Weather :**

There are lots of API available to find out weather some API requires city name some api requires geocoordinates

**Date:**

If you want your time to be accurate then use some datetime finder api.you may have to pass city name or geocoordinates. Actually this step is required if you want to show present timezone date time even if student overrides the timezone details in the device otherwise you could simply use `NSDate` class

**Note:**

You will have to google a lot to find the right APIs